# Underscore filter an object

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I have an object like below I'd like to remove all key value where key = '/'

```
let routes = {
   '/dashboard': {
        name : 'Dashboard',
        component : appDashboard,
        icon: 'fa fa-dashboard',
        subRoutes: {
           '/': {

              component:appDashEcommerce
          },
          '/ecommerce': {
              name : 'Ecommerce',
              component:appDashEcommerce
          },

        }

    },
    '/apps': {
        name : 'Apps',
        component : appAppsPage,
        icon : 'fa fa-th',
        subRoutes: {
            '/': {

              component:appInbox
            },
            '/mailbox': {
              name : 'maibox',
              component : appInbox,
              icon : 'fa fa-th',
            }
      }
};
```

my current code

```
var ret2 =  _.omit(routes, function(val, key, object) {
         if(_.has(val , 'subRoutes')){
            _.omit(val.subRoutes , function(v, k, o) { 
                return key === '/'
            })
          }else{

            return key === '/' || key === '*'
         }
       })

     console.log(ret2)
```

Comment: Did you have a question or were you just getting that off your chest.

Comment: sorry this is a question , do you have an answer ?

Comment: I have one, it's much simpler though, because it doesn't use an entire library to something really simple -> https://jsfiddle.net/qspunug6/1/

Comment: @adeneo please answer question to mark this as correct , this seems to work

Comment: i really hate this people who down vote valid questions without any reason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you're using the wrong variable for your inner function.

EDIT: Sorry, I got lazy and tried to write without testing. The above assertion is correct, but there are a few other errors as well, addressed in the updated code below

https://jsfiddle.net/e708gyna/

```
//_.omitBy should be used for functions according to the lodash spec
var ret2 =  _.omitBy(routes, function(val, key, object) {
  if(_.has(val , 'subRoutes')) {
    //In order to use the result below, we need to store it
    val.subRoutes = _.omitBy(val.subRoutes , function(v, k, o) {
      //Since you're running this on the subRoutes
      //you need to test the key that you've defined
      //for this inner handler
      return (k === '/');
    })
  } else {
    return (key === '/' || key === '*');
  }
})
```

Comment: Fixed. There were a few other errors I didn't fix in the first run.